# how to use tensorflow dataset map function correct for string column

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

m using tensorflow datasets api

and i have a data with a string column that can represents a binary option

(something like ("yes" or "no")

i'm wondering if i convert it into 1 and 0 (integer value) respectively, and leave the other columns unchanged

my skeleton functions is:

```
def mapper(features,target):
    #features["str_col"] TODO "MAP this when yes to 1 when no to 0"

    #return features with x transformed # TODO
```

can u assist?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert a bool to int:

```
y = tf.equal(features["str_col"], 'YES')
y = tf.cast(y, tf.int32)
```